# Someone please explain contractions in Java code syntax

Tags: java

A question from dummy....  What is the full version of code below?
How to interpret it in classic (long) version of code?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .push()
                .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                .getCurrentUser()
                                .getDisplayName())
                );
```

Comment: What's "contracted" about this code?  This is perfectly normal Java.

Comment: There are no contractions there, just extra whitespace (including line breaks).  The extra space is not significant.  If anything, then, this code is *expanded*, not contracted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This code excludes many variable declarations and assignments for the purpose of readability. It is most definitely contracted. White space doesn't count toward expanding the code because white space isn't code - it's formatting.

Comment: Also, everyone who down-voted this question is exactly what's wrong with this community. A new programmer comes in asking for help with a very specific question, and rather than look at the question and try to help him understand, you make it sound like he's an idiot and should already know this stuff. Sure, you could read a book on this to get the syntax down, but not everyone understands technical jargon right off the bat, and not everyone has access to learning facilities to help with things like this. Take a moment and ask yourself whether you'd like to be treated this way.

Comment: Apparently the OP was satisfied with your answer, @cwharris, but I'd never have guessed that that was what he was looking for.  Chaining method invocations together is not a "contraction" in my book.  Declaring a variable to receive the result of every method invocation is not a baseline style.

Comment: @cwharris Thank you for explanation, I'm civil engineer actually, programming is my hobby)) I didn't know where to start to learn something about this "trick" in code. Could you please provide more information to read about this?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but Jetbrain's has educational versions of their IDEs and they look pretty cool. They've built in programming lessons in to the editor. Codecademy is another place to learn about coding. https://www.jetbrains.com/education https://www.codecademy.com

Comment: See [**method chaining**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just Java

```
SomeClass1 instance        = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
SomeClass2 reference       = instance.getReference();
SomeClass3 push            = reference.push();
SomeClass4 authInstance    = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
SomeClass5 currentUser     = authInstance.getCurrentUser();
SomeClass6 displayName     = currentUser.getDisplayName();
SomeClass6 message         = input.getText();
SomeClass7 messageAsString = message.toString();
SomeClass8 chatMessage     = new ChatMessage(messageAsString, displayName);

push.setValue(chatMessage);
```

Note: Code is ridiculously formatted for the purpose of clarity. Please don't use formatting like this example in your code.

Comment: Thank you! It's an official example from Google Firebase docs...

Comment: @maxpodgorny any time you see a method invocation, there's the opportunity for a method to return a value (unless it is a void method). When you see methods chained together like in your example, it just means the next method is operating on the value returned by the previous.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I've got it :))

Comment: @maxpodgorny Also, try not to refer to yourself as a "dummy". You're new to this. Why would you be good at it? The brain and nerves learn by building myelin around your neurons, insulating them to make them fire faster and more effectively. The more you do something the better you get at doing it that way (even if it's not the "best" way). Keep doing and you'll keep learning. Eventually reading and understanding things like this will become second nature (like driving or riding a bike). Don't let the bullies make fun of you just because you haven't ridden a bike before.

Answer (score 3):

The called methods all return an *object* (apart of the last one), not `void`. In some other languages, you'd call them *functions* as opposed to *procedures*.

Since the method returns an object, you can in turn call a method on that returned object, and chain the calls like this.

It's equivalent to something like this, if that makes it more clear to you:

```
<some class> var1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
<some class> var2 = var1.getReference();
<some class> var3 = var2.push();
var3.setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getDisplayName())
);
```

Comment: No no no, I meant the syntax... Particularly .getInstance(),  .getReference()  .push() and setValue(...) , why are they written in column?  And why there is no semicolon after each? How to interpret syntax if it would be written without contraction?

Comment: No contraction here, and no semicolons. You call a method, you get an object, and then you call a method of that object. I'll try to clarify in an edit.